# how implementing IInternetSecurityManager.ProcessUrlAction & URLPOLICY_QUERY in C#?

Tags: c#

As Mentionned here [IInternetSecurityManager::ProcessUrlAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms537136(v=vs.85))  i do return a S_OK when i send a URLPOLICY_ALLOW in the *pPolicy.
And i return S_FALSE for and anything else.
it work for URLPOLICY_DISALLOW but not for URLPOLICY_QUERY.

i always get the same result that URLPOLICY_DISALLOW when i send a URLPOLICY_QUERY with S_FALSE.
(i tried to return S_OK instead, but i get the same result that URLPOLICY_ALLOW if i do that.)

So i was wondering, is someone have a working example to show ?  =/

also, it is very important that i don't add/change the security behavior in the registry for either local machine or current user. it must remain at the application level only.

Answer (score 0):

i think i have understand the "microsoft concept" (but i can't affirm i'm right).
i was excpecting the InternetSecurityManager to popup a dialog box if i return a URLPOLICY_QUERY with S_FALSE. but that's probably where i'm wrong.

So my guess is that in ProcessUrlAction :

1. you must read in the registry to see if the policy is URLPOLICY_QUERY
2. pop your own dialog box (if the flag PUAF_NOUI haven't been pass)
3. depending of the user decision : return either S_OK or S_FALSE with *pPolicy = URLPOLICY_QUERY